# Magento2.4.2 Create order Programmatically not working using cronjob

Tags: magento2, php, place-order, magento2.4.2

I've tried a viral solution and followed this https://webkul.com/blog/create-quote-and-order-programmatically-in-magento2/

The quote is created successfully but error occurred when place order through cronjob only.

```
$orderId = $this->cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($quote->getId());
```

And the following error occurred

```
 Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\InventoryIndexer\Model\Queue\ReservationData, Argument 2 passed to Magento\InventoryIndexer\Model\Queue\ReservationData::__construct() 
must be of the type int, null given, called in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

Comment: Did you execute command
" php bin/magento setup:di:compile "

Comment: Yes. I'm facing issue through cronjob only.